# Any ideas for a model (class diagram) to track visitors for a website?

Tags: tracking, ip-geolocation, visitor-statistic, unique

My background idea is to create a software layer that merges all the things related to anonymous visitors:
-uniqueness
-sessions
-geo-localization
-hit counter
-basic reporting
-distributable APIs
-thermal map for forms
Many talk well about [Piwik](http://piwik.org). I'm at the beginning of discovering process so I need to know if I have to reinvent the wheel or lay on the giants' shoulders.
PS: [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) is an option as now

Comment: consider a system like digg. How it does to understand have I rated for an item already? Now I'm surfing http://kigg.codeplex.com/ to find out those funcionalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piwik is definitely the way to go, the only thing it doesn't do is "-thermal map for forms" but the rest is covered, and more. Full featured API (For analytics reports & for tracking data), nice UI, etc.